# How to solve a SonarQube S3267 warning, "Loops should be simplified with "LINQ" expressions"

Tags: c#, linq, sonarqube

Consider the following code (which is a simplified version of my actual code):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string[] data = { "one", "two", "three", "stop", "four", "five" };

    foreach (string item in data) // S3267 
    {
        if (!process(item))
            break;
    }
}

static bool process(string text)
{
    if (text == "stop")
        return false;

    Console.WriteLine(text);
    return true;
}
```

At the indicated line, this provokes a SonarQube S3267 warning, "Loops should be simplified with "LINQ" expressions".
For now, I have just suppressed this warning.

My question is this: Is there a good way to rewrite this which is as readable?

Resharper suggests this:

```
foreach (var item in data.Where(item => !process(item)))
{
    break;
}
```

but that just provokes SonarQube warning "Loops with at most one iteration should be refactored" (or similar), and  I think that's less readable than the original version.

I also thought of:

```
foreach (var item in data.TakeWhile(process))
{
}
```

but that obscures things in my opinion.

There's also

```
_ = data.All(process);
```

but now we're just getting silly.

I'm also considering adding my own extension methods:

```
public static class MyEnumerableExt
{
    #pragma warning disable S3267 // Loops should be simplified with "LINQ" expressions

    public static void ProcessUntil<T>(this IEnumerable<T> sequence, Func<T,bool> process)
    {
        foreach (var element in sequence)
        {
            if (process(element))
                break;
        }
    }

    public static void ProcessWhile<T>(this IEnumerable<T> sequence, Func<T, bool> process)
    {
        foreach (var element in sequence)
        {
            if (!process(element))
                break;
        }
    }

    #pragma warning restore S3267 // Loops should be simplified with "LINQ" expressions
}
```

Then the call site would just be:

```
data.ProcessWhile(process);
```

but I don't really like adding too many extension methods, especially if they are only used in very limited situations.

Is there any nicer way to resolve this? (I realise that many answers to this question would be a matter of opinion, but I'm looking for a concrete unopinionated suggestion.)

(I think just suppressing the warning is the right approach, but I'm open to suggestions!)

Comment: Opinionated: I'd just supress the warning as it doesn't really make sense in this case. Simplifying this through LINQ would actually just make things harder to understand, not simpler. IMHO, your original `foreach` loop is perfectly fine.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Yes, that's what I thought - I just wonder if there's something I'm overlooking. I suppose I should really post this on the Code Review site...

Comment: (After reading the guidelines for the Code Review site it appears that I should not post questions like this there.)

Comment: From your question, could you try to use `FindIndex` as `data.ToList().FindIndex(0,x=>x=="stop")` to instead `ProcessUntil` method?

Comment: @D-Shih The way I understood this is the OP has a complex method that at some point returns false as in "processing no longer needed" - the strings here are just a simplification as stated at the beginning of the post.

Comment: I agree with Camilo but I'd go one further and disable the warning for the entire solution. It adds no value. Saying loops "should" use LINQ is subjective and, in my view, not something to be "warned" about. Save that for things that are important. Things like this only end up with people ignoring/missing genuine things they should be warned about, because the list of warnings has been watered down to include things like this. Warnings should contain useful information. This one just generates noise.

Comment: @JohnH That SonarQube warning isn't completely mindless - it does normally recognise when a loop can indeed be simplified, so I don't want to throw the baby out with the bathwater.

Comment: SonarQube appears to be assuming that `process` is a (pure) boolean test on `item` and not a method whose main purpose is side effects and returns a continue flag. I do think the loop is somewhat unusual form in that it uses `foreach` but breaks out early, and does nothing to save where it stopped but I don't see a better replacement  unless you are willing to use an enumerator since LINQ should be for functional (pure) methods and not processing.

Comment: The very simple alternative `data.TakeWhile(process);` would make more sense if the method were named more descriptively; e.g. `ProcessItemIfItemCanBeProcessed() { } ` --> `data.TakeWhile(ProcessItemIfItemCanBeProcessed);`. But I'd probably go for a separate condition check and processing method (if possible) myself: `foreach (var item in data.TakeWhile(condition)) { Process(item) }`.

Comment: This warning is generraly useful (really simplified my several loops before) but today I come up with SonarLint offering a loop to convert to a *terrible* LINQ expression. So I ignored it. I am a big fun of static code analysis tools but no software is perfect in the world. Sometimes they give misleading warnings and it is important to know when to ignore those problematic warnings. @JohnH has very good points but disabling this rule for the entire solution is an excessive measure I think.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure I would call this an improvement but it does avoid the use of `break` in a `foreach`. It makes me think it would be nice if there was an expression version of `foreach` like the new expression `switch` that would let you use enumeration in other looping contexts, like `while`.

```
var dataEnum = ((IEnumerable<string>)data).GetEnumerator();
while (dataEnum.MoveNext() && process(dataEnum.Current))
    ;
```

If your real `data` is not an array, you wouldn't need the cast, which is required since the non-generic version of `GetEnumerator` was added to arrays before generic `GetEnumerator` was added to the language, and they chose not to have the type-safe version be preferred on arrays.

If C# did have an expression `foreach`, I would have it work like this:

```
while (data foreach var item && process(item))
    ;
```

You could have an `out` after `foreach` but I think that can be implied. Since I can't figure out a way to have a stateful method in C#, this extension method is as close an implementation as I can come up with:

```
public static class IEnumerableExt {
    public delegate bool ForEachDel<T>(out T item);

    public static ForEachDel<T> NewForeach<T>(this IEnumerable<T> src) {
        var e = src.GetEnumerator();
        return (out T item) => {
            var res = e.MoveNext();
            if (res)
                item = e.Current;
            else
                item = default;

            return res;
        };
    }
}
```

Which you would use like:

```
var dataForeach = data.NewForeach();
while (dataForeach(out var item) && process(item))
    ;
```

Comment: That's an interesting idea, but ultimately I think it's still not as readable as the original version. I think I've pretty much decided to just suppress the warning.